# Azure Function EventHubTrigger Attribute not finding event hub name

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am having an issue where my event hub name is not found when I publish my function to a function app (It works fine locally, if I just run it in VS2017).  I am recieving the following error on the published function in the azure portal when I open the function.

[image]

This is the attribute on my Run method.

```
public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("%eventHubName%", Connection = "eventHubConnection")]string data, TraceWriter log)
```

Now if I don't include the %'s wrapped around the eventHubName, when I run it locally it will say that it can't find the eventhub (Using the eventHubName string literally instead of looking into the local.settings.json like the connection string), but it will work when it is published.  I am wanting to avoid putting the actual name in the attribute as different environments will have unique event hub names.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions will use the `local.settings.json` file when you are developing locally. When your Function App is running on Azure, it will read the values from the Application Settings.

Using the `%zzz%` is the correct way to read settings, so this makes me question if you have a setting called `eventHubName` in Application Setting when you deploy to Azure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure